# Maven won't load my custom library

Tags: java, maven

I have two projects both use maven. The project A is a utility library, and I use `mvn install` to my local maven repo. The project B is a web app, it has a dependency on A library.

when I run B project use `mvn jetty:run` it don't load  `a.jar` in my local maven repository, but if I execute `mvn package` to package my web app, the a.jar will in its WEB-INF/lib.

I tried under maven 3.1 and maven 3.2, both have the problem.

I'm new to Maven 3 and have been using Maven 2 for many years, why can't this solution work as before?

**Edit:**

From the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>me.donnior</groupId>
  <artifactId>rtl</artifactId>
  <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:**

My problem is that my own installed A.jar can't be found when run `mvn jetty:run`, but others third-party jars that downloaded from network can be found in class path.

**Updated:**

I figure it out is a jetty plugin's dependency problem, can be closed now.

Comment: Show us the relevant `<dependency>` elements of the `pom.xml` in the B project.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>me.donnior</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtl</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I noticed Maven3 has a new resolution for local repository, but it's  very confusing.

Comment: Check your local repository (`~/.m2/repository/me/donnior/rtl/0.3`) if there is an actual JAR somewhere there. If there is none then delete entire `rtl` folder and perform `mvn install` on the project A again. If this time local repository hosts a proper JAR then try to package your `B` application again.

Comment: @PawełWyrwiński the actual Jar is there, and will be included in my packaged B app if I execute `mvm package`, the problem is it will not be on the classpath when I run `mvm jetty:run`

Comment: Whats mvm commands. It should be mvn.

Comment: @Orion I didn't noticed that mvn will be auto-correct to mvm

Answer (score 1):

**mvn jetty:run** dont perform packaging Lifecycle.

It enables project without requiring that it is packaged. In this mode every component of the project is used from its origin location.

try to use `jetty:deploy-war`instead as it perform **mvn package** lifecycle phase as well.

Comment: I know that, my problem is that when I run `mvn jetty:run` all other jars downloaded from network can be found except my own installed library.